# How can I call a macro from another worksheet without opening it?

Tags: excel, vba

I have two worksheets; in the first one called "Foglio1.xls" I have the function "printValue", in the second one I want to call this function.

To do that I used this code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.Run "'C:\Users\fra31\source\repos\Key Visor\Key Visor\Foglio1.xls'!printValue"
End Sub
```

It works well, but I don't want to open a new window, because the file "Foglio1.xls" is already open.

can someone help me?

Comment: Try `Application.Run "'Foglio1.xls'!printValue"` if the file is already open

Comment: it says "Error 1004, we can't find the path, possible moved,renamed or deleted"

Comment: You sure the file and the Macro exist with the exact same name ? Shouldn't file name be `.xlsm` as it has Macro ?? Try `Application.Run "'Foglio1.xlsm'!printValue"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the workbook is already open this should work.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.Run "'Foglio1.xls'!printValue"
End Sub
```

Comment: yes, it's already open, but i get "Error 1004, Sorry we couldnt find Foglio1.xls. Possible moved, renamed or deleted"

Comment: @FrancescoZappalà are you sure it's `.xls` and not `.xlsm`?

Comment: It's xls, I'm sure

Comment: @Mathieu since it's a Sub in the Thisworkbook module,  won't that require qualification?

Comment: @FrancescoZappalà is the macro a public parameterless procedure in a standard module?

Comment: ok i solved the problem. this code was written in "ThisWorkBook" folder. i moved it in a module. Thank you